# Why Spring security prevents POST?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have written controller. I have 2 method. First if GET, second is POST.
Everything works well!

**when** I add spring-security.xml  **POST does not works!**
my filter:

```
     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I have this error:

```
 HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

my spring-security looks like this:

```
   <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
            <-- remove from here
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')" />
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="NAME"
                password-parameter="PASSWORD" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
            <csrf />
           to here -->
        </http>
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        ...
```

The most interesting thing is that, **if I remove** content of  http tag everything **works**...
I have commented the too... why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the <csrf /> that causes the problem.  Post should sent the csrf token as well.  See also [Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html)

Comment: CSRF errors usually cause other error message, status 403?

Comment: should I remove <csrf /> ? or is there any another way to solve this problem?

Comment: This depends on your requirements. See the link on the answer to get the idea

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send form with method post. you need to send a token like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Just add this tag into youo form.